# split one big QVD file into many based on year

Tags: qlikview

split one big QVD file into many based on year and the date column contain the year is formated '20230103' .. etc

never tried as always wrong

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume that the qvd is named `FullData.qvd` and the date field is named `SalesDate`.

In order to split the qvd we have to extract the possible years from `SalesDate` field.

Once we have the years values then we can start looping through the values and load data for the relevant year and store it in qvd.

The approach below is more suitable for large qvd but it will make sure that the data is read in [optimized way](https://www.quickintelligence.co.uk/qlikview-optimised-qvd-loads/)

```
// load all dates (distinct) and determine the year for each one of them
SalesDates:
Load 
    Distinct
    SaleDate          as SaleDateTemp,
    left(SaleDate, 4) as SalesYear
From 
    [lib://Downloads/SalesData.qvd]
    (qvd)
;

// once all years are known - start the loop
for each i in FieldValueList('SalesYear')

  // load all dates for the year
  SalesDatesTemp:
  Load
    SaleDateTemp as SaleDate
  Resident
    SalesDates
  Where
    SalesYear = $(i)
  ;  

  // load data only for the dates that are into the "current" year
  // using "Exists", in this instance, will make sure that the qvd 
  // is read in optimized load
  SaleYearData:
  Load
      *
  From 
      [lib://Downloads/SalesData.qvd]
      (qvd)
  Where
       Exists(SaleDate)
  ;
  
  // store the "current" year data into a qvd suffixed with the year itself
  Store SaleYearData into [lib://Downloads/SalesData_$(i).qvd]; 

  // in order to prevent data concatenation these tables
  // have to be dropped in each iteration
  Drop Tables SalesDatesTemp, SaleYearData;

next

// drop the date <-> year mapping table
Drop Table SalesDates;
```

The result is multiple qvd files:
[image: Generated files]

Using optimized load when loading the data:
[image: Optimized load]

Couple of examples to ensure that the data in each qvd is for only one year:
[image: Example results]